# Getting undefined when firebase data stored to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code. I want to store data from firebase to store to an object (`this.chatThread`).

```
chatThreadMessageFetch(mobileNumber, fromID) {

    this.chatThreads=[];
    return firebase.database().ref(messaging/${mobileNumber}/chatThread/${fromID}).orderByKey()
       .once('value').then(snapshot => {

            snapshot.forEach((messageSnapshot)=> {

             key=messageSnapshot.key*-1;

            this.chatThreads[key]=messageSnapshot.val();

         });
        });

}
```

When I console logged the `this.chatThreads` I'm getting `undefined`. 
Following is my firebase database.
[image]

On contrary, I get data if I assign `this.chatThreads = messageSnapshot.val()`

Comment: what this will do `key=messageSnapshot.key*-1;` ?

Comment: since the key value is something like `-1509964621958`, I multiply it with -1 to make it a positive integer

Answer (score 2):

you can use `push` to store data

```
this.chatThreads[key].push(messageSnapshot.val());
```

or

```
this.chatThreads.push(key+':'+messageSnapshot.val());
```